# n-fold Iterated Integral

Tags: integration

I have been trying to prove the below equation. It has been a while, thrashed few papers but couldn't do it. Can I ask help on that ?.

Let $x_0$ be a positive real number, and let
$\mathrm{f}:\left[0,x_{0}\right] \to \mathbb{R}$  be continuous. Show that

$$
\int_{x_{1} = 0}^{x_{0}}\int_{x_{2} = 0}^{x_{1}}\cdots
\int_{x_{n} = 0}^{x_{n - 1}}\mathrm{f}\left(x_{n}\right) =
{1 \over \left(n - 1\right)!}\int_{t = 0}^{x_{0}}
\left(x_{0} - t\right)^{\,n - 1}\,\mathrm{f}\left(t\right)
$$

Comment: What are these integrals being integrated with respect to?

Comment: This is the full exact question. It was asked under the Fubini's Theorem in Shurman's 'Calculus and Analysis in Euclidian Space' book. Section 6.6 Question 6.6.12. Using Induction is recommended by book.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_formula_for_repeated_integration